# LAN communication for Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, networking, lan

I would like to make 2 computers communicate over the LAN using Unity without 3rd party plugins.
I have found some code that works for localhost but when I execute the server on one PC and the client on the other I can not get it to work.

Here is the code I currently use:

The server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Server: MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;    
    private Thread tcpListenerThread;
    private TcpClient connectedTcpClient;

    void Start()
    {
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForIncomingRequests));
        tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;
        tcpListenerThread.Start();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SendMessage();
        }
    }

    private void ListenForIncomingRequests()
    {
        try
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8052);
            tcpListener.Start();
            Debug.Log("Server is listening");
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                    {
                        int length;
                        while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            var incomingData = new byte[length];
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);
                            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);
                            Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());
        }

        Debug.Log("Exiting...");
    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {
        if (connectedTcpClient == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                string serverMessage = "This is a message from your server.";
                byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverMessage);
                stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);
                Debug.Log("Server sent his message - should be received by client");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }
    }
}
```

The client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region private members     
    private TcpClient socketConnection;
    private Thread clientReceiveThread;
    #endregion
    // Use this for initialization  
    void Start()
    {
        ConnectToTcpServer();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SendMessage();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ConnectToTcpServer()
    {
        try
        {
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
            clientReceiveThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incoming data.  
    /// </summary>     
    private void ListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            socketConnection = new TcpClient("192.168.1.8", 8052);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    // Read incoming stream into byte array.
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        var incomingData = new byte[length];
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);
                        // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                        string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);
                        Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }

        Debug.Log("Exiting...");
    }
    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to server using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    private void SendMessage()
    {
        if (socketConnection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                string clientMessage = "This is a message from one of your clients.";
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientMessage);
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.                 
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);
                Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the client I get this error:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or connected host has failed to respond

I also tried allowing the port on the firewall on both computers but it also didn't work.

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Use for listener : tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPAny, 8052);  Then start listener first and use IP address in client of the listener.  The listener and client if they are on different machines cannot be the same IP address.

Comment: I used for the listener: tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8052); and for the client I used the IP address of the server from ipconfig but I get the same result.

Comment: The issue could be a few things 1) Not router between client and server.  From cmd.exe use ping to determine if there is a route 2)  There may be another connection using same port.  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a and check status of port number on both client and server. 3) The port is blocked by virus checked.   There are other reasons but this is where to start.  You can also use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help determine the issue.  The sniffer will tell if message is being sent and if a response is being returned.

Comment: Hello, 1) ping from the client finds the server with no problem. 2) netstat does not display any other connection using the same port. 3) I disabled the antivirus from both computers but didn't work. About the wireshark, I don't know how to use it but I spotted that when I try to connect from the client to the server I get a message "4180 155.542827 192.168.1.7 192.168.1.8 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 50559 → 8052 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1". (192.168.1.7 is the client and 192.168.1.8 is the server)

Comment: Using Netstat on server do you see a listener?  It looks like the client attempted to connected to server and connection failed so a retry occurred.  The server need to start a listener before the client attempts to connect.  I do not like your server.  First the server is constantly running in the while loop using a lot of CPU resources.  I prefer using Async rather the Syn method.  Second you can receive with TCP a message with zero bytes which I think is happening if you see the sniffer results Len=0.

Comment: I checked the netstat with netstat -na | find "8052" and it finds that the port is listening. I run the server before the client of-course. I will try the Async method, if you could also send me a link that would help me it would be great. Although keep in mind that the current code works on localhost but does not work on different machines on the same network. Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: Update: Just tried the async method, it also works for localhost but fails for LAN.

Comment: It is interesting that Ping works and the server is listening, but you connection is not working.  That is leading me back to the sniffer results you posted with a length of zero.  Does sniffer show any packets returning an ACK?  TCP every packet will have an ACK.  Every IP message has a sequence number.   So the sniffer is showing sequence number 50559.  So there should be another message with 50559.  Also check if you see [FIN] which indicates the connection closing.  Looking at your code I think the issue may be with messages that have zero bytes is causing code to exit your while loop.

Comment: I use the msdn examples as a guide, but do not like everything in the examples.  The examples only show the TCP layer and not how to use with a complicated Application that send different types of messages : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I have added some comments to know if the code exits the while loops, I will update it above, it seems like it does not. Wireshark on both machines detects 5 things with the same code every time I turn the client on (after the server of-course).    --> 1) 24710 1372.758220 192.168.1.24 192.168.1.8 TCP 66 50239 → 8052 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1   -->2) 24718 1373.760279 192.168.1.24 192.168.1.8 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 50239 → 8052 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1    --> 3,4,5 are exactly the same as 2).

Comment: I get the same output when I use the async method.

Comment: TCP will try 3 to 5 times if no ack (message in reverse direction) is seen.  Can you try PING from server to client.  So cases ping will work in one direction and not opposite direction.  The PING  is returned in ethernet card at interface while ACK is sent after interface.  I'm think one of two things A) The mask is wrong in the server B) You are getting CRC errors.  I usually check for CRC with long ping messages >ping -t -l 65500  where t is send until ping is stopped and l is length where 65500 is largest length.

Comment: There is one more possibility. You have two machines with same IP address. So if you disconnect ethernet cable on machine and PING. If you still get a response then you get another machine with same IP. – jdweng 10 mins ago

Comment: I think you spotted the issue, ping from the server to the client does not work for some reason! Ping from server to a third computer on the same LAN works though... Do you have any idea why I can't ping the specific client?

Comment: From cmd.exe >IPCONFIG /ALL which will give interfaces and mask.  Usually the mask is blocking the IP or you have two subnets (two ip addresses) and message is going out wrong interface.  Also try ping with computer name instead of IP.  There may be a router or server that is blocking the message.  There are smart router that will block messages if router see two different source IP addresses.  The smart routers only allow one source ip address fro each ethernet cable.

Comment: I think that after I turned the option for both machines to be detectable over the network ping started working for both ends. But still that didn't solve the issue :( Do you have any ideas on what to check now?

Comment: I do not know what you turned on, but you may not of fixed issue.  It has been a long time since I seen ping work one direction and not other direction.   When this happened I found to get ping to work temporarily I did a ping in opposite direction and then it work  until I rebooted the machine.  I'm suspect either CRC errors, tow machines with same IP, or mask error on interface.  Seen case of all three in the past with similar issues.  Go back to sniffer and see if symptoms changed.

Comment: You may also have some routing loops.  The TTL in the sniffer will give indication of loops.  The TTL get decremented every time a message gets forwarded though a router or server.  So you can tell the number of hops a message is taking.  So if you ping from server to client and then on client use sniffer you can see the TTL number.

Comment: I checked the messages from the wireshark and they remain the same. When I ping the client from the server with wireshark running on the client it detects 4 requests and 4 replies with TTL = 128. (The same messages are detected on server's wireshark when I ping from the client to the server)

Comment: I would also like to mention that on resources monitor (windows 10)  the firewall status on Unity.exe is Not allowed, not restricted which I am not sure if it is good or not.

Comment: Alright! That was the problem... Unity automatically adds some rules on the firewall not allowing the connections... I disabled those rules and it worked :O

Answer (score 1):

I will add the solution here for anyone that has the same issue as I had.

**Unity Editor automatically adds a firewall rule that blocks the connections**, you need to disable this rule, or set it to "Allow the connection if it is secure".

For those that are not sure how to set the firewall rules here are the steps that I took and it worked (windows 10).

Click start, type "firewall" then click on "Windows defender firewall with advanced security", click "Inbound Rules", search for the rule with the red block sign in front of it called "Unity {your version} Editor" and double click it, set the Action to "Allow the connection if it is secure" or just disable it.
Then you will also need to create a new rule allowing the connection from the specific editor at the specific port.

Keep in mind to use the Resource Monitor to check what is going on with the connection.